# Set and subsets link by prime numbers

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers

I have a bit idea to solve this problem for small $n$ by programation but I think for $n>100$ I will need maths to help me. My problem is :

> Let S be the set of prime numbers less than n.
>   Find the number of subsets of S, the sum of whose elements is a prime number.

This problem seems to be very difficult, I'm woriking on it for few month when I have time, but for the moment I saw no possible symetries in the problem. It's "not difficult" to find all subsets the sum of whose elements is an even number but it just can give me an approximation of the number of all subsets and not the exact number.

Any hints or partial answers will be appreciated

PS : I'm a chemist maths is not my work, however if you have a very technical thing to say, say it please, if I have to take 4 months to understand I will take them, I like learn and have an intensive brain activity !

Comment: So you want to find this number as a function of $n$??? Good luck with that!

Comment: Not necessarily but for $n=10000$ could be great :D

Comment: A short Python script could do the job (in about $10,000$ years).

Comment: That's why I need maths, I think we can find the solution for $n=1000$ if we are good at maths ! :)

Comment: @barakmanos Dynamic programming approach is about $O(n^2)$ I guess.

Comment: Question: If the set is $\{2, 3, 5\}$ does this produce $4$ or $5$ subsets?  Specifically I'm asking whether or not _both_ $\{2, 3\}$ and $\{5\}$ are counted as subsets even though they both add to give the same prime of $5$.

Comment: Yes they are differents

Comment: It seems to me that the "best" you can do is know all of the unique sums for set of prime numbers, adding to that list would be simple: just add the next prime to each unique sum of the previous primes (properly accounting for newly created duplicates).  But I would imagine this number (the number of unique sums of $n$ prime numbers) to be quite large--and you cannot discard non-prime sums as you grow the list because indeed a non-prime sum may later lead to a prime sum (say $3+5=8$ then later $11 + (3 + 5) = 11 + 8 = 19$).

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: Why did you say $O(n^2)$? My answer describes the DP but it is $O(\frac{n^3}{\ln(n)^2})$, not $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well let $p_k$ be the $k$-th prime and $f(k,n)$ be the number of subsets of the first $k$ primes that have a sum of $n$. Then obviously $f(k,n) = f(k-1,n) + f(k-1,n-p_k)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}^+$ and $n \in [1..\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i]$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i \in O(k^2 \ln(k))$ as $k \to \infty$ by the prime number theorem, this algorithm will take $O(k^3\ln(k))$ time for $k$ primes, which is $O\Big( \frac{n^3}{\ln(n)^2} \Big)$ for primes below $n$. After this we can just find the sum of $f(k,q)$ over all primes $q \in [1..n^2]$ to get the desired number for the first $k$ primes below $n$, which takes $O(n^2)$ using the sieve method. I doubt there is any better approach to this problem because of the (lack of) structure.

**Edit**

As Chris Culter below pointed out, if we want the exact answer rather than to a certain fixed precision, then the time complexity becomes much higher because the answer grows exponentially with respect to $n$. I'm not sure what is the exact asymptotic behaviour, but given any $k$, heuristically taking $n \sim \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^k p_i \sim \frac{1}{4} {p_k}^2 ( \ln(p_k) - 1 )$ should roughly maximize $f(k,n)$ with value roughly about $2^{O(k)}$, and hence the computations of $f(k,n)$ for a large number of values of $n$ would take about $O(k)$ time each. This would give a total of roughly $O( k^3 \ln(k) )$ time for computing all the values of $f(k,n)$ for a given $k$, and hence $O( k^4 \ln(k) )$ time in total for $k$ primes, which is $O\Big( \frac{n^4}{\ln(n)^3} \Big)$ time for primes below $n$. All this would not be relevant if we only want to compute the answer to a fixed number of significant digits.

Comment: @Shadock: This can handle up to $n = 1000$ comfortably in 1 second on an ordinary computer, but you'll have to wait about 20 minutes for $n = 10000$.

Comment: Did you mean $f(k,n) = f(k-1,n) + f(k-1,n-p_k)$?

Comment: @ChrisCulter: Absolutely. I was blur when typing the answer just now.

Comment: Okay! One other nit: it may take $O(n^3/\ln(n)^2)$ addition operations using bignums, but using fixed-size machine registers, that probably takes something like $O(n^3/\ln(n))$ time.

Comment: ...Actually, the more I think about it, it's probably worse than that. We need something like $O(n)$ bits, so it probably takes $O(n^4/\ln(n)^?)$ time.

Comment: @ChrisCulter: Yes I was assuming our numbers fit in the registers, which is going to be the case for the kind of $n$ that this algorithm can handle. For arbitrary precision the numbers involved will be of size $O(\log(n))$ so the complexity will go up to slightly more than $O(\frac{n^3 \ln\ln(n)}{\ln(n)})$ using one of the fast multiplication algorithms. Not so bad as $O(n^4)$. In general arbitrary precision arithmetic will only cause extra logarithmic factors.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking that the typical working values of $f$ are themselves exponential in $n$, so a logarithmic factor in $f$ is linear in $n$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter: No, the problem gave $n$ to be the upper bound on the prime numbers, so their size is only $O(\log(n))$.

Comment: For a concrete example, the largest $f(82,m)$ is $f(82, 4139)=2886573718204791=2^{51.358\ldots}$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you still disagree with my asymptotic complexity for the arbitrary precision variant of the problem?

Comment: Oh thank you, I will try when I'll have a bit of time :)

Comment: @Shadock: You're welcome!

Comment: Yes I delete my comment just after write it sorry ^^

Comment: Yes, I still disagree. I'm saying, roughly, that $\log f\sim n$. If I'm not mistaken, you seem to be saying that $f\sim \log n$?

Comment: @ChrisCulter: Oh! I had wrongly assumed that $f$ was polynomial in $n$. Hahaha! Okay time to edit my answer to put that consideration in. Thanks for persisting! =)

Answer (score 2):

As a reference point, there are 17193362135842433291 prime sums among primes up to $331$ (the 67th prime). That's as far as we can go using 64-bit arithmetic. For more values, see http://oeis.org/A071810 "Number of subsets of the first $n$ primes whose sum is a prime", where T. D. Noe has contributed a list up to the 100th prime.